# AngularJS service function execution order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS.
I created a service to retrieve a file using $http.get, but I can't figure out
how to control when the service function is executed.

My controller's function is injected with the service.

When the page first loads, the service function is invoked first.
Instead, I want the service function to be invoked after clicking a button.

Or maybe I shouldn't use a service function?

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, myService) {
    
    $scope.searchValues = function () {
        $scope.value = "search.json";
        myService.setValue($scope.value);
        console.log(" in searchValues " + $scope.value);
    };
});


app.service("myService", function($http, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var value ;

    this.setValue = function(valueSelected) {
        console.log("in service:  " + valueSelected);
        value = valueSelected;
    };

    $http.get('http://juubaker.github.io/' + value).then(function(data) {
        console.log("in service 2:  " + value);
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });


    this.getValue = function() {
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

Thanks

Comment: take a look at `ng-click` or if it's in a form `ng-submit`. Either way using service is appropriate, it's just a matter of wrapping the `myService.setValue()` method in an event triggered function

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Actually, on the button, I do use ng-click and the function is invoked.  However, the service was already invoked prior to clicking the button.  I'm not sure how the event function can trigger the service function call.

Comment: Thats the normal way of initialising. If that doesnt happens you will get unknown provider myService error in your controller

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service looks totally fine. Just don't call your `myService.setValue`  method in your controller immediately like that. Instead, create a method that you run via `ng-click`

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http,  myService) {
  $scope.updateValue = function(){
    myService.setValue($scope.value);
  }
});
```

And your template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value" />
<a ng-click="updateValue()">Save Value</a>
```

The logic inside your controller method is run immediately upon initialization of that controller, which is why you're running into this issue.

Comment: Oh great catch .  OK, I moved the setValue to a function.  And the service is not invoked at initialization.  However, I also have an http.get function in my service and it's still getting invoked at initialization.  I'll check the code again and post if I can't resolve this.

Comment: Correction from last comment.  The Service was invoked twice before clicking the button.  After the last suggestion, I moved the service.setValue call to a function.  But the $http.get is invoked at initialization.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't just put your http request inside of your `setValue` method?

Comment: Actually, no particular reason.   I was following an example and it was suggested to put the $http.get inside a service.  Is there a best practices for how to run the http service ?  It's ok to run it inside a controller ?  Thank you.

Comment: It seems like the service is unnecessary in your example. How about just doing: https://gist.github.com/dboskovic/29da57d883253d2df342

Comment: Thank you very much  @dboskovic the http.get is no longer running at initialization.